# Исходники библиотечных функций

Tags: библиотеки

Народ подскажите где брать исходники библиотечных функций. Везде только описания как их использовать. Как использовать я и сам разберусь, хочется разобраться в алгоритмах.
В частности функция qsort с прототипом:

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
        int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

Нужно само тело, чтобы понять, что она делает с параметром `compar`

Answer (score 2):

Нужно смотреть, что за библиотека и что за функции. В данном случае Вы пишете о функции из стандартной библиотеки. Ее описание можно найти в стандарте или например на сайте [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/?kw=qsort) или [qsort](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). Так как это стандартная функция, то ее можно поискать в сорцах к компиляторам. Быстрый поиск находит [такое](http://www.takatan.net/lxr/source/lib/qsort.c?v=2.4.21-47.EL).

Если нужны другие фукции - я обычно ищу сорцах (у меня линукс и это делает очень легко).